# Frameworks that support complex nested forms ala Rails' accepts_nested_attributes_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, frameworks, lisp, ocaml

I'm working on a small side project for a friend and I need to build complex forms dynamically from a set of predefined types which in-turn are persisted via the underlying object model.

So far I'm using Rails 2.3.4, [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes), and a bit of [Javascript](http://github.com/alloy/complex-form-examples/tree/a234fde4419836f277d7e340657f1d8418911d68).

There's nothing wrong with this, I've just about got it modified to handle arbitrary nesting and ordering... but having done RoR for the past two years it would be fun to use this as an excuse to learn something new. That said I'm lazy so it has to be as easy as the RoR solution.

Suggestions? Bonus points for Lisp, Scheme, or OCaml :-)

Thanks-- Mike

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try Weblocks.

Read this: http://www.defmacro.org/ramblings/ui-dsl.html

Web site: http://weblocks.viridian-project.de/